# Is there a value to show how fragmented is a group?

Tags: categorical-data, variance, descriptive-statistics

I would like to know if there is a way to calculate a number that can show how fragmented is a group?

It should be something like "variance of categorical data"?

For example I want to see how fragmented is Android/iOS in terms of OS version. The number would be high for Android, where there are a lot of versions, and the usage percentage of each version is small. For iOS, the number would be small, since there is a dominant usage percentage of one version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different measures of variability of a categorical variable, see e.g. Wikipedia's [list](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diversity_index) .

A frequently used one is Simpson's index of diversity (aka Herfindahl index). It equals the sum of squared relative frequencies of the categories. As such, it estimates the probability that two randomly chosen iOS users have the same version.

Comment: Thanks! Simpson's index of diversity is what I'm looking for! Is there a way to tell if the largest segment is significantly dominant?